# How to POST image in imgbb.com via python?

Tags: python

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=YOUR_CLIENT_API_KEY" --form "image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
```

How to post an image in imgbb?
I am beginner. I can not post any image.

```
url = 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload'
key = '232565fc1a4f0d24578d9aeadc0b43ab'
res = requests.post(
    url, 
    data = {
        'key': key, 
        'image':b64encode(open('a.png', 'rb').read()),
        'name': 'a.png',
    }
)
```

Comment: You got any answer? I always get response 400.

Answer (score 9):

That is what worked for me.

```
import base64
import requests

with open("fig1.png", "rb") as file:
    url = "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload"
    payload = {
        "key": key_imgbb,
        "image": base64.b64encode(file.read()),
    }
    res = requests.post(url, payload)
```

Comment: how do you get the response JSON? the res object seems to just have <Response [200]>

Comment: @wongz You can get it via res.json()